# how to check if the radio button are required in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know how to check if the radio button is required.
I am using jquery, i tried to use

```
console.log($("#radio").prop("required"));
```

But it is not working.

Comment: console.log($("#radio").attr("required"));

Comment: use `attr` instead of `prop`

Comment: In other input types I used prop("required") and it is working. why not in radio and checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$('input').attr("required")` or `$('input').get(0).hasAttribute("required")`

```js
 

console.log($('input').attr("required"));
console.log($('input').get(0).hasAttribute("required"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" required> test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#radio").attr("required");
```

Or:

```
$("#radio").is("[required]");
```

The first one uses the attribute property (makes a `getAttribute` call). The second uses a CSS selector. So if you want to select all the inputs that are required you'll need something like: `$("input[required]")`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use attr() in place of prop as used here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('required')){
      console.log('Required');
    }
    else{
      console.log('Not Required');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" required /> test1
<input type="radio" /> test2
```